# PHP Global variables for an externally included, AJAX loaded PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, global-variables, session-variables

Is it possible to access a Global variable declared in a file, e.g. a `header.php` file, from another external PHP file named `content.php` that has been loaded with an AJAX call, without using GET or POST?

e.g.

index.php:

```
<?php

    include 'header.php'; //The global variable $SESSIONID is defined in this file

    echo '<div id="for-content"></div>';

    include 'footer.php';
?>
```

header.php

```
<?php
    $SESSIONID = "asdf";
?>
```

content.php:

```
<?php
    echo $SESSIONID;
?>
```

And the AJAX call:

```
$("#for-content").load("content.php");
```

Comment: As long as the global variable is in the same scope, it should be accessible, yes. Although if you are accessing only content.php in your AJAX call then you should re-include the `header.php` file. PHP is a runtime server-side code and needs everything defined at run-time.

Comment: No, it's not possible like that. The AJAX call is a totally unrelated PHP script run, it doesn't know anything about the script that created the page earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it isn't possible to get access to the global variable. You have to include `header.php` again. AJAX is loading the document (in your case `content.php`) asynchronous with a complete new http-request. So it will loading `content.php` without any data.

The only possible solution is to send `$SESSIONID` with AJAX-Call via `POST`:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'content.php',
  data: {session: '<?php echo $SESSIONID; ?>'},
  success: function(data) {
       $('.target').html(data)
    },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

or `GET`

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'content.php',
  data: {session: '<?php echo $SESSIONID; ?>'},
  success: function(data) {
       $('.target').html(data)
    },
  dataType: 'html'
});
```

Comment: ok thanks - i can't send it with a POST/GET because that would enable the user to see the SESSIONID and then make special requests to another server with that SESSIONID, so i'll just have to update the content of the <table> itself contained in `content.php` with an AJAX request without reloading the entire `content.php file`

Comment: oh .. okay. I just added the solutions for `GET` and `POST`. Anyways maybe interesting for other readers.